# Can't os.rename a formated string

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I can't rename the file with a format string, gets that error

```
import codecs
import html_text
import os

file = codecs.open(r'C:\Users\itayh\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\potter\1.html', 'r', 'utf-8').readlines() # open and read html file (makes it a list)
x = file.index('<option value="1">Chapter 1: A Day of Very Low Probability</option>\n') # gets the index of the names i want to save starts
names_list = [html_text.extract_text(line) for line in file[x:x + 122]] # makes a list of the names i change with
i = '1'
for name in names_list:
    old_name = fr'C:\Users\itayh\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\potter1\{i}.html'
    new_name = fr'C:\Users\itayh\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\potter1\{name}.html'
    os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    i = str(int(i) + 1)

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\itayh\\OneDrive\\שולחן העבודה\\potter1\\1.html' -> 'C:\\Users\\itayh\\OneDrive\\שולחן העבודה\\potter1\\Chapter 1: A Day of Very Low Probability.html'
```

But it working when i do it without formatting the string

```
old_name = fr'C:\Users\itayh\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\potter1\1.html'
new_name = fr'C:\Users\itayh\OneDrive\שולחן העבודה\potter1\Chapter 1: A Day of Very Low Probability.html'
os.rename(old_name,new_name)
```

Comment: but when i don't pur `r` before the string i get this error    `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
`